# oracledb.exceptions.DatabaseError: ORA-00911: invalid character but when i run in oracle the sql success

Tags: python, oracle, flask

I'm using flask and oracle as my backend and I'm trying to get the data but it keeps saying invalid character even though when I run the SQL inside Oracle the SQL give the output but when inside Flask it was error invalid character

```
 cur = con.cursor()
    user_id = session["user_id"]  #Type int
    cur.execute(
        """
        SELECT DISTINCT p.*,
        (CASE 
            WHEN user_id = :1 THEN 'joined'
            ELSE 'not'
        END) AS Result,
        (CASE 
            WHEN pub.request_to_join IS NULL THEN 'Private'
            WHEN pub.request_to_join = '1' THEN 'Public (Request)'
            ELSE 'Public'
        END) AS STATUS
        FROM ipm_project p
        LEFT JOIN ipm_project_public pub ON pub.project_id = p.id
        LEFT JOIN ipm_project_private pri ON pri.project_id = p.id
        JOIN ipm_project_team_junction pt ON p.id = pt.project_id
        JOIN ipm_project_team i ON i.id = pt.project_team_id
        ORDER BY p.id ASC;
        
        """, (user_id,)
    )
    
    columns = [col[0] for col in cur.description]
    cur.rowfactory = lambda *args: dict(zip(columns, args))
    all_projects = cur.fetchall()  // GETTING INVALID CHARACTER ERROR
```

[This image shows that SQL above I run inside Oracle and the output shows , The SQL was same like above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okTk2.png)

[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qq8v8.png)

Comment: Please show the whole error message, which usually indicates WHERE in the query the error happened.  If you copied this from a web site, it could be something as simple as one of the spaces is actually a Unicode non-breaking space.

Comment: I just include the whole error message, please check

Comment: Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots ([how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Hmm, that's not helpful.  What do you use to edit your code?

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the semi-colon `;` from the end of the SQL command. That is an end-of-command indicator when working from a command line tool like sqlplus, but is generally unnecessary when using a compiled program in a language like Java, where it is presumed that each SQL execute instruction is a single command. This helps prevent SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Per the [documentation](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/sql_execution.html):

> SQL statements should not contain a trailing semicolon (“;”) or
> forward slash (“/”). This will fail:
>
> ```
> cursor.execute("select * from MyTable;")
> ```
>
> This is correct:
>
> ```
> cursor.execute("select * from MyTable")
> ```

So do this:

```
cur.execute(
    "SELECT DISTINCT p.*,
    (CASE 
        WHEN user_id = :1 THEN 'joined'
        ELSE 'not'
    END) AS Result,
    (CASE 
        WHEN pub.request_to_join IS NULL THEN 'Private'
        WHEN pub.request_to_join = '1' THEN 'Public (Request)'
        ELSE 'Public'
    END) AS STATUS
    FROM ipm_project p
    LEFT JOIN ipm_project_public pub ON pub.project_id = p.id
    LEFT JOIN ipm_project_private pri ON pri.project_id = p.id
    JOIN ipm_project_team_junction pt ON p.id = pt.project_id
    JOIN ipm_project_team i ON i.id = pt.project_team_id
    ORDER BY p.id ASC", user_id)
```